# SammyK LaravelFacebookSdk - can't obtain an access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I've searched for a Laravel Facebook SDK and I found [this](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/tree/1.2) package that works with Laravel 4.2 (my laravel app version). I use this just to get my facebook page posts but I got into a problem, my access token expires every 2 hours or in some cases because of other reasons like facebook logout, etc.

I found out that there are 2 ways to [handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/), either to extend the access token, either to request a new one using the old access token.

The questions is how to request a new access token because I store it into my database and I need to get my facebook page posts all the time?

I've followed [this](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/tree/1.2#obtaining-an-accesstoken-object) instructions but for me it does not work.

When I use this code:

```
try
{
    $token = Facebook::getTokenFromRedirect();
    echo "Success<br>";
    print_r($token);
}
catch (FacebookQueryBuilderException $e)
{
    // Failed to obtain access token
    echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

the only thing what I see on the screen is `Success` and that is all, it's like the `$token` is empty.

I've also checked [Facebook Query Builder](https://github.com/SammyK/FacebookQueryBuilder) which is included into `SammyK LaravelFacebookSdk` and tried to use `getTokenFromCanvas()` insted of `getTokenFromCanvas()` but I get this error: `Method getTokenFromCanvas does not exist`.

Any idea to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

By default Facebook will return a user access token that expires after 2 hours. You can extend it for a long-lived access token that'll last 60 days.

Once you obtain an `AccessToken` entity in Laravel Facebook SDK 1.2, you can extend it like it shows in [the example](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/tree/1.2#user-authentication-example):

```
try {
    $token = $token->extend();
} catch (SammyK\FacebookQueryBuilder\FacebookQueryBuilderException $e) {
    dd($e->getPrevious()->getMessage());
}
```

In your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/issues/49) you mentioned:

> What I want to achieve is to get the posts from my facebook page

You can use a page access token to grab your page posts. You can obtain a page access token from the [`/me/accounts` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/accounts).

If you use a long-lived user access token to obtain the page access token, the page access token will never expire so it's ideal to store in your database to pull posts from a page.

See [more about handling access tokens](https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4). Good luck! :)

Comment: Where are you putting the `Facebook::getTokenFromRedirect();` line? That needs to go in your callback script. It's the URL that Facebook redirects the user to after they authorize your app. You define that callback URL in when you generate the login URL with `Facebook::getLoginUrl()`. By default it will be example.com/facebook/login. Make sure you see [the full example](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/tree/1.2#user-authentication-example).

Comment: Sorry to hear that a free 48-hour turn-around time on an open source support request wasn't sufficiently fast enough for you. But very happy you figured it out! :)

Comment: I get it! Deadlines on projects force us to implement things less-than-perfectly & if you can't find a solution you gotta move on to the next thing. It's all good. :) Glad you figured out your issue!

Comment: i think this i for old version . How to do this in  version 3.0 ??